# Since $i$ can be used for $90^\circ$ rotations, and $\sin$ and $\cos$ are orthogonal, why is it that $\sin t\neq i\cos t$ and $i\sin t\neq-i\cos t$?

Tags: complex-numbers, orthogonality

As I know imaginary unit number $i$ can be used for $90^\circ$ rotation. For example, between $5$ and $5i$ there are $90^\circ$.

Also $sin$ and $cos$ are orthogonal too.

> So why $\sin \theta \neq i \cos\theta $
> or  $ i \sin\theta \neq -i\cos\theta$?

**I think I found my answer in below equation of Euler:**

$$e^{inx} = cos(nx) + i sin(nx)$$
so
$$ cos(nx) = e^{inx}-isin(nx)$$
It is not exactly how I imagined but yes It gives me the answer.

also as @José Carlos Santos stated in comments

quote:

> They are orthogonal with respect to the inner product
>
> $$ \langle f,g\rangle=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)g(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$
> This has nothing to do with 90∘ rotations in the plane

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What do you mean when you state that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are orthogonal?

Comment: Thank you! I mean -at least as I know- there are 90 degrees between cosinus and sinus.

Comment: I still have no idea about what you are talking about. The sinus and the cosinus are *functions*. What's the angle between two functions?

Comment: Sorry If I couldn't explain it very well. For examle lets say $cos\theta$ falls into a number  like a. $cos\theta=a$  and also $sin\theta=b$. So since $cos(\theta+90)=sin(\theta)$ I tried to relate these two with imaginary unit number. But there might be a confusion of terms then. I asked it because in electrical engineering $i$ is used to distinguish quantites that have 90 degrees. For example a resistor and capacitor has got 90 degrees in terms of phasors and we use $i$ operator to indicate it and then use it in our calculations. From this aspect I tried to relate sin and cos

Comment: Actually, $\cos(\theta+90)=-\sin(\theta)$. Nevertheless, there's a big jump from here to asserting that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are orthogonal. For each individual $\theta$, $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ are simply real numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your correction about - sign. It is interesting that sinus and cosinus functions are used in Fourier Series because they are orthogonal. [Here](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-Fourier-series-use-cosine-and-sine) This is not an academical source but it explains here.

Comment: They are orthogonal with respect to the inner product$$\langle f,g\rangle=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)g(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$This has nothing to do with $90^\circ$ rotations in the plane.

Comment: Oh... Now I got my answer. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Resolution of a vector signal  $(  A \cos \theta, A \sin \theta)  $ in the first quadrant.

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos I believe this *does* have something to do with rotations, but the connection is not that straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following is helpful to know. Since Euler we know
$$ e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x). $$
This implies by multiplication
$$ i\,e^{ix}=i(\cos(x))+i(i\sin(x))=-\sin(x)+i\cos(x). $$
Thus, in **some sense, it seems** that
$\,i\cos(x)=-\sin(x)\,$ and $\,i\sin(x)=\cos(x)\,$ if you are
**not** looking at the equation **carefully**, but it will
give rise to false results.

As for orthogonality, as functions or signals, the
functions $\,\sin(x)\,$ and $\,\cos(x)\,$ are $\,90^\circ$
out of phase. This may be considered as a reason to state that they
are orthogonal, and there are other definitions of orthogonality.